# C++: The iterator of struct in the class pointed by the iterator of class pointer is not dereferencable

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

In this code, 'vector iterator of class pointer' and 'vector iterator of struct' loops for total twice.

but with `for (vector<VkQueueFamilyProperties>::iterator iter2...`, the following exceptions caused:

> vector iterator not dereferencable

Am I did the wrong way to access the iterator?

I want to know why the second iterator cannot be initialized.

Part of RVulkan.cpp:

```
#include "Core/AppInfo.h"
#include "RVulkan/RVulkan.h"

/*
Some source code for class function definition ...
*/

bool RVulkan::Initialize()
{
    VkResult result;
    result = CreateInstance();
    if (result != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw runtime_error("Failed to create vulkan instance");
        return false;
    }

    EnumeratePhysicalDevice();
    bool found = false;
    for (vector<VkPhysicalDevice>::iterator iter
        = pDevice.begin(); iter != pDevice.end(); ++iter)
    {
        RVulkanDevice RVulkanDeviceClassTemp(this, &(*iter));
        RVulkanDeviceClass.emplace_back(move(&RVulkanDeviceClassTemp));
        found = true;
    }

    if (!found) {
        throw runtime_error("Failed to find any graphics devices with Vulkan supported");
        return false;
    }

    bool foundGraphic = false;
    bool foundCompute = false;
    for (vector<RVulkanDevice*>::iterator iter
        = RVulkanDeviceClass.begin(); iter != RVulkanDeviceClass.end(); ++iter)
    {
        (*iter)->GetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties();

        /* exceptions: vector iterator not dereferencable */
        for (vector<VkQueueFamilyProperties>::iterator iter2
            = (*iter)->queueFamilyProps.begin(); iter2 != (*iter)->q   ueueFamilyProps.end(); ++iter2)
        {
            if (iter2->queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT) {
                foundGraphic = true;
            }
            if (iter2->queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_COMPUTE_BIT) {
                foundCompute = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!foundGraphic && !foundCompute) {
        throw runtime_error("Failed to find any graphics devices for draw and compute with Vulkan supported");
        return false;
    }
    else if (!foundGraphic) {
        throw runtime_error("Failed to find any graphics devices for draw with Vulkan supported");
        return false;
    }
    else if (!foundCompute) {
        throw runtime_error("Failed to find any graphics devices for compute devices with Vulkan supported");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

RVulkan.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "RVulkan/RVulkanHeader.h"
#include "RVulkan/RVulkanUtil.h"
#include "RVulkan/RVulkanDevice.h"
#include "RVulkan/RVulkanCommandBuffer.h"

class RVulkanDevice;
class RVulkanCommandBuffer;

class RVulkan
{
public:
    RVulkan();
    RVulkan(const RVulkan& copy);
    RVulkan(const RVulkan&& copy);
    ~RVulkan();

    bool Initialize();
    void DeInitialize();
    void Update();

public:
    vector<const char *> instanceLayerNames;
    vector<const char *> instanceExtensionNames;
    vector<RVkLayerProperties> instanceLayerProperties;
    vector<VkExtensionProperties> instanceExtensionProperties;

    VkInstance instance;
    vector<VkPhysicalDevice> pDevice;
    vector<RVulkanDevice*> RVulkanDeviceClass;
    vector<RVulkanCommandBuffer*> RVulkanCommandBufferClass;

private:
    VkResult CreateInstance();
    void DestroyInstance();

    VkResult EnumeratePhysicalDevice();
};
```

RVulkanDevice.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "RVulkan/RVulkanHeader.h"
#include "RVulkan/RVulkanUtil.h"
#include "RVulkan/RVulkan.h"

class RVulkan;

class RVulkanDevice
{
    friend class RVulkan;
public:
    RVulkanDevice(RVulkan* _RVulkanClass, VkPhysicalDevice* _pDevice);
    ~RVulkanDevice();
    RVulkanDevice(const RVulkanDevice& copy);
    RVulkanDevice(const RVulkanDevice&& copy);
    RVulkanDevice& operator=(const RVulkanDevice& copy);
    RVulkanDevice& operator=(const RVulkanDevice&& copy);

protected:
    bool GetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties();
    VkResult AddDevice(const uint32_t _queueFamilyIndex);
    bool RemoveDevice(const VkDevice _device);
    bool RemoveDevice(const uint32_t _deviceIndex);
    bool RemoveAllDevice();

public:
    RVulkan* RVulkanClass;
    VkPhysicalDevice* pDevice;

    vector<VkQueueFamilyProperties> queueFamilyProps;
    vector<VkDevice> device;
};
```

RVulkanDevice.cpp - GetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties:

```
bool RVulkanDevice::GetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties()
{
    uint32_t queueFamilyPropsCount;

    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(*pDevice, &queueFamilyPropsCount, NULL);
    if (queueFamilyPropsCount <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    queueFamilyProps.resize(queueFamilyPropsCount);
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(*pDevice, &queueFamilyPropsCount, queueFamilyProps.data());

    return true;
}
```

RVulkanHeader.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <system_error>
#include <assert.h>

#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

using namespace std;
```

[Debugged with VS2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlvIw.png)

[Debugged with VS2017 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBKVI.png)

[Full Source Code (need vulkan)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aud5wAIjV2zGx04NU_DRhDCSgVp-)

Comment: provide declaration for RVulkanDevice class

Comment: added declaration

Comment: Probably you need to include VkQueueFamilyProperties header. Just a forward declaration is not enough.

Comment: `RVulkanDeviceClass` that is a strange name.  What is its type, and *is that exactly what your code looks like or did you simplify anywhere*?

Comment: I am suspicious of `GetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties`.

Comment: I added the forward declaration just for easy understanding. declation of `RVulkanDeviceClass` is `vector<RVulkanDevice*> RVulkanDeviceClass`.

Comment: VkQueueFamilyProperties header is already included: `#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>` in `#include "RVulkan/RVulkanHeader.h"`

Comment: It doesn't make it easier to understand, it adds confusion. You should add the include statements instead. Basically strip down your code as much as possible while keeping/adding every relevant bit to reproduce the error, i.e. a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't add a link to full source code. We want questions to be useful for readers in years to come. Links can go dead. Provide a MCVE and add the code to your question.

Comment: that exception means that you ran out of vector bounds somehow. it happens, for example, if you try to dereference end(). It's not  a guaranteed behavior, e.g. g++ - compiled program won't generate this exception. You'd really need to debug this and check if your vector is populated. Also might want so sanity checks. Current architecture rises a lot of questions, e.g., why to store pointers as fields

Comment: before, I opened and debugged cmake project in VS2017 itself, but when I create, compile and debug the project of VS2017 only with cmake, I see different exception: "vector iterator not incrementable". also, debugger show me that `itet2 iterator` and `queueFamilyProps vector` have normal value. you are right, I need to debug in detail to check this.